# Can the "now" or "tween" parameters of .animate's step function "hold" an array index number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-animate

Here's kind of the "literal" explanation of what I am trying to accomplish:

*I am trying to have something happen to index 0 in array B when, originally, something happens with index 0 of array A; the same for indexes 1, 2, 3, etc.* (Let me know if this explanation isn't good enough.)

I sort of got this working with a "for" loop (in which, if an image in array "links" hits a certain position, an image in array "shadows" appears, all based on the same index number):

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep"];
var shadows = ["#shadow1", "#shadow2", "#shadow3"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {

        $(links[i]).animate({

            top: '0'
        }, {

            duration: 2250*(Math.random()*1.25+1),

            easing: 'easeOutBounce',

            step: function(n) {

                for (var e=0; e<links.length; e++) {

                   if ($(links[e]).position().top >= 400) {

                       $(shadows[e]).attr("src", "images/home/shadow.png");
                   }
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

However, I am wondering if it's possible to do something similar using the parameters of the "step" function. Another SO user helped me figure out how to change something based on ["Number/now"](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)'s position relative to the parent. I'm wondering if "Number/now" or "Tween" (or could another parameter be inserted?) could or do store the current index number, and if that current index number could be "sent" to another line of code that then makes changes to a different array.

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep"];
var shadows = ["#shadow1", "#shadow2", "#shadow3"];

$(document).ready(function() {

    links.forEach(function(n){

        var link = $(n);

        link.animate({

            top: '0'

        }, {

            duration: 1250,

            easing: 'easeOutBounce',

            step: function(img, tween) {

                //if "now" is -19 or below
                if (img > -20 ) {

                    //change the falling image picture
                    $(this).attr('src', "images/home/frown1.png");

                   /*I would also like to be able to change the "src" of the array "shadows", but only if it is right below the current falling image/only if the index number of "img" would be equal to that of "shadows".*/

                  //kind of like this
                  shadows[$(this).indexNumber or img.indexNumber].attr('src', "help.png");

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My apologies if this is confusing, and thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that there's any reason for the animation of each element to check on the status of all the others; they'll be wasting a lot of energy redundantly checking eachother.

Comment: OK I think I see the root of your question. This is a good example of a case where the *right* place for those "id" references in the "shadows" array should really be kept in the DOM, as "data-" attributes on the animated elements. That would make it trivial for the "step" callback to find the right shadow for the animated element just by checking a `.data()` value.

Comment: If you post an outline of what your HTML actually looks like, it'd be possible to suggest simpler solutions. It might not even be necessary to alter the markup, depending on its structure.

Comment: Will post HTML/CSS soon. **EDIT: I'll create a fiddle to work with.** Could you provide an example of how I could make use of a .data() value in this context? I don't think I've ever used one before.

Comment: Sure, but you may not have to. If your HTML structure is such that finding the "shadow" element corresponding to one of the animated elements is simple, then that'd be the thing to do.

Comment: **Here's the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/mLemotv9/4/ EDIT: The idea is that the falling images would trigger corresponding images (shadows) beneath them, and the shadow images would change depending on the distance. Right now I just have the targeted images (the Facebook logos) changing size when they reach a certain point. *Thanks a bunch, I always appreciate SO people who are willing to help me.*

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mLemotv9/5/ includes randomized durations. Am also reading http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: OK [here is a revision of the first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atk91pwg/) with "data-" attributes added to the HTML. It should be pretty clear what's going on: in the "step" function, the code just has to fetch the value of that attribute, add a "#" to it, and then find it in the DOM that way.

Comment: Also if you're doing animation this way, look into [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity) it's pretty much a drop-in replacement for the jQuery `.animate()` function and it's *much* faster.

Comment: ... oops except Velocity doesn't support `step` apparently; it uses a "progress" callback that's a little different.

Comment: Thanks mate. I *think* I get the gist of it: the data in each "img" in "footer" sort of acts as a "channel" to send instructions back to each corresponding "img" in "footer2". If an "img" in "footer" gets to -19 or greater, a hashtag (to reference an id) and the data for that specific id ("this") is developed, and the attribute and information to change is sort of relayed back to the actual id in "footer2", where the changes are made. (something like that, I think) **Question:** is there a reason you used "prop" instead of "attr"? "attr" seems to work too.

Comment: Yes `attr` here will work as well as `prop`.  Yes your understanding is correct. It's a nice technique to put information in a DOM element so that code that's responding to some event can figure out what other parts of the DOM are related without having to have a complicated mapping system to reflect the situation on the JavaScript side.

Comment: Cheers, and thanks for pointing out Velocity. However, despite studying JS for the past few months (on and off), I definitely still consider myself a beginner and don't want to complicate matters any more than necessary.